# Почему parseFloat возвращает только целую часть числа?

Tags: javascript, строки, float

Имеется переменная с типом данных "string", и имеет следующие значения:

```
latitude = "45.21414";// эти переменные получаю из json файла с помощью fetch();
longitude = "38.53254";
```

И изменяю тип данных с помощью parseFloat:

```
    latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
    longitude = parseFloat(longitude);
```

В результате чего получаю только целую часть числа - 45 и 38.
Почему происходит сие действо для меня остаётся загадкой..

```js
let latitude = "45.21414";
let longitude = "38.53254";
latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
longitude = parseFloat(longitude);
console.log(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Не воспроизводится, я вижу число целиком с дробной частью

Comment: `parseFloat` сам по себе ничего округлять не будет, думаю что-то не договариваете (не показываете) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас там запятая вместо точки.

```js
let latitude = "45,21414";
let longitude = "38,53254";
latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
longitude = parseFloat(longitude);
console.log(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: В вопросе точка. Попытка угадать?

Comment: @andreymal Попытка? Не вижу других вариантов.

Comment: Есть как минимум ещё вариант отбрасывания дробной части «в результате» — автор же не показал, где и как он выводит

Comment: @andreymal Сейчас узнаем.